# is current ASPX page a List or Library page?

Tags: javascript

**Is there a better way of testing if the current ASPX page is a List (or Library) page?**

I now have:

```
if(
     !( 
       document.location.pathname.indexOf('/Forms/')<0 
        && 
       document.location.pathname.indexOf('/Lists/')<0
      )
  ){
     //is a page from a List or Library
   }
```

Comment: Hint: Look at the JS object `ctx`. It will be present on any page that contains a list view. Undefined if not. Not a complete answer to your question though hence adding as a comment.

Comment: ctx is available on any page with a ListViewWebPart, including the pages (eg. from the SitePages library) I need to exclude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the current list base template ID using JSOM. Page Library is 850 and it's not listed in the MS ref below.

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);

context.load(list);


context.executeQueryAsync(
   function() {
        alert(list.get_baseTemplate());
   },
   function(){
    alert('error')
   }
  );
```

`_spPageContextInfo.pageListId` gives you the current page's list ID

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx